# my app uses a jwt authentication token

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, jwt

this is regarding incoming sms from a mobile phone via twilio.

when testing with postman (and I append the header with a Bearer JWT token I received from my app), everything works fine and my app can recognise the request.

but sending an sms results in a 401 error as my endpoints are not reachable. any proven ways of doing this or do I have to hack my app to bypass incoming requests from twilio and just every request that comes from that twilio number.

please help!

Comment: You'll need to show code and which part is causing the error.

Comment: You should provide a bit more context, what errors you're seeing, etc

Comment: basically my api uses jwt and I have to make twilio requests (post via webhooks) be validated in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will not send a bearer token JWT in requests because it doesn't know to authenticate with your application like that.

You will need to bypass the JWT check for requests from Twilio. If you're using express that should be straightforward and if you share some code we can look into how to make that happen for your app. On the up side, there are other security methods you can put in place instead.

[Twilio supports HTTP authentication via basic or digest auth](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#http-authentication). If you can set the endpoint in your app to require authentication in this way instead, then it can be secured.

You can also check against the `X-Twilio-Signature` header that is sent with every request to [validate that the request came from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests). There is a guide on [how to validate Twilio requests in Node.js with Express](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-secure-your-express-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests).

Comment: Thanks Evangelist and all. Implemented authentication by using X-Twilio-Signature and did it via the manual process, so longer but better. Thanks for all the help..

Comment: Do you mind marking the answer as correct though, so that others can see it helped? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Evangelist and all. Implemented custom authentication by using X-Twilio-Signature and did it via the manual process, so longer but better. Thanks for all the help.. PS: twilio will have to later think down the line of bearer headers which will make life easy for application developers instead of us using bespoke method to authenticate. Just a thought.

Comment: philnash - how do i do that

Comment: There should be a checkmark to the left of my answer, click that. I’ll mention bearer tokens, but we do support basic and digest Auth too, so there’s plenty of standard approaches too.